# What's the purpose of glNormal3f in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es

What's the purpose of glNormal3f in OpenGL ES? If there is no immediate mode available in OpenGL ES, for what would I use glNormal3f? Example code would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's for the same reason that there is a glColor function. If the normal of your whole geometry is the same for all vertices you could specify it with glNormal before calling glDrawArrays/glDrawElements.

Comment: Exactly that's it.. On OpenGL|ES it glNormal sets the default-normal. Imho they could would have done better if they had removed the function. glMultiTexCoord exists for the same reason btw.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of is that it is there to support efficiently expressing surfaces where many vertices share the same normal. With the arrays-based approach, you'd have to create an array with the same value repeated for each vertex, which wastes memory.

I find it curious that the [manual page](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/) (OpenGL ES 1.1, there) doesn't even mention it. I found one [iPhone programming tutorial](http://deimos3.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/FeedEnclosure/utah.edu.1668842900.01668842919.1705385205/enclosure.pdf) (PDF) that even claimed `glNormal()` was not there anymore.

Comment: By "where many vertices share the same normal", do you mean "where all vertices drawn in a given `glDrawArrays` call share the same normal"?  Is that a correct understanding of it?

Comment: I can't find "iPhone programming tutorial" from the University of Utah on iTunes/Podcasts. Please update the link.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES 1.1 does mention it but yes that's an error there in the iPhone programming tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use these functions anymore. Stick to the glXXXXArray(). I suspect that they are just left overs hanging in there to make OpenGL to OpenGL ES transfer easier.

Answer (score 0):

In **OpenGL|ES glNormal3f()** is not a deprecated function,

because it is useful for rendering **flat 2D shapes** in the {X,Y} plane:

instead of using:

```
glEnableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );
glNormalPointer( GL_FLOAT, 0, vbuf + normal_offset );
```

it is simpler and it requires less VBO memory to call:

```
glNormal3f( 0, 0, 1 );
```

Comment: please read the formatting help to understand how to tag code :-)